# Unit of Work implementation on top of EF Core cleanly supporting explicit loading

Tags: design-patterns, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, ef-core-6.0

I have implemented a Repository/Unit of Work on top of EF Core's DbContext:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
  IUserRepository Users { get; }
  IRoleRepository Roles { get; }
  int Complete();
}
```

Obviously IUserRepository is a repository of User objects built over the corresponding DbSet:

```
public interface IRepository<D, E> where D : DbContext where E : class, new()
{
  E Get(long id);
  IEnumerable<E> GetAll();
  IEnumerable<E> Find(Func<E, bool> predicate);
  void Add(E entity);
  void Remove(E entity);
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<MyDbContext, User>
{
  IEnumerable<User> GetCreatedInPeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
  IEnumerable<User> GetInactive();
}
```

My question is, is there a clean way to support explicit loading through such an implementation? For that, one normally uses the Entry API of DbContext, which is hidden behind the unit of work. One could expose Entry on the unit of work, but then one would be able to write queries starting from a specific entity (have queries leaked out of the unit of work). Since one of my goals is to only expose IEnumerable and not IQueryable (queries leaking), I wanted to ask the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. It dawned on me how simple it was as I was writing it. This allows exposing the loading functionality without exposing query functionality. IQueryable stays wrapped within the unit of work, all queries remain there.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IUserRepository Users { get; }
    IRoleRepository Roles { get; }

    void LoadReference<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, R?>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class;
    void LoadCollection<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, IEnumerable<R>>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class;

    Task LoadReferenceAsync<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, R?>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class;
    Task LoadCollectionAsync<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, IEnumerable<R>>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class;

    int Complete();
}

public void LoadReference<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, R?>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class
{
  dbc.Entry<E>(entity).Reference<R>(propertyExpression).Load();
}

public void LoadCollection<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, IEnumerable<R>>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class
{
  dbc.Entry<E>(entity).Collection<R>(propertyExpression).Load();
}

public Task LoadReferenceAsync<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, R?>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class
{
  return dbc.Entry<E>(entity).Reference<R>(propertyExpression).LoadAsync();
}

public Task LoadCollectionAsync<E, R>(E entity, Expression<Func<E, IEnumerable<R>>> propertyExpression) where E : class where R : class
{
  return dbc.Entry<E>(entity).Collection<R>(propertyExpression).LoadAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is the n + 1 anti-pattern all over the place.

Comment: @GertArnold would you care to clarify please?

Comment: What if you load 100 entities in one query and then want to load their collections (let's say one each)? With this setup you need 100 additional queries. And 100 queries for each subsequent collection/reference. This is very bad design. If you want to load object graphs (= entities with loaded collections/references) you must use `Include`. If your repository pattern makes that impossible then ditch it or redesign it.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your response. My design absolutely supports that. (btw, it's not my design but by some fellow much smarter than me). For example, I can write a specific query in my specific repo like IUserRepository.GetAllIncludingRoles() or even override the default Get() method of the base repo to include... Include(). (Making it virtual was my idea, like exposing part of the Entry API): public override IEnumerable<User> GetAll() { return dbContext.Set<User>().Include(u => u.Roles); } Of course the DbContext can be configured to do this automatically, this is just another option.

Comment: @GertArnold I find the additional explicit loading capability extremely useful. For example, right now I am going through a list of entities just wanting to process additional related info for one of them. Exposing just part of the Entry<> API ensures I can load without the possibility of queries leaking outside the repo. If I change the DAL I can reimplement the loading functions or replace them with empty implementations if the new DAL loads automatically. Thanks again for your input, I will do some reading on the n + 1 problem when I have some free time, to have it in mind just in case.